# Python Graph Libraries

Tags: python, apache-spark, graph

I have a graph data stored in a text file in the shape: **v1,v2,w** (i.e. edge from v1 to v2 with weight w)

How to use python ready libraries in the case of the described text file, in order to calcuate in-degree for each vertex and other operations.

Note: I will run it with spark

Thanks,

Comment: Please **clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need**. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

networkx and igraph are commonly used libraries to analyse graphs in python.
Both have facilities to read in a graph from your specified file format:

igraph:

```
import igraph 
g = igraph.Graph.Read_Lgl("/path/to/file.txt")
degree = g.indegree() # returns list
```

networkx:

```
import networkx as nx
g = nx.read_weighted_edge_list("/path/to/file.txt", create_using=nx.DiGraph)
degree_centrality = in_degree_centrality(g) # returns dict; value * number_of_nodes returns degree
```

Comment: thank you for the information, but is I tried to import netwrokx as you mentioned and its gave error although I installed it successfully! and it is folder exist in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Comment: The error was related to python version .. but it can't take file as you said !! it seems that the format of data not as required for igraph or networkx!

Comment: is GraphX support python or only for scala? @Paul